# Connect google glasses to android app via wowza (live streaming)

Tags: android, google-glass, live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I try to connect the google glass to my own android app and i tried to use wowza live to display live streaming on it, but i don't know why its not work. Any body have idea ????

this is my all code:
https://github.com/andermaco/GlassStream

This is part of my code that give error in it, what is the wrong ??

```
try {
                // We parse the URI written in the Editext
                Pattern uri = Pattern.compile("rtsp://(.+):(\\d+)/(.+)");
                Matcher m = uri.matcher(url); m.find();

                ip = m.group(1);
                port = m.group(2);
                path = m.group(3);

                // Connection to the RTSP server
                if (mSession.getVideoTrack() != null) {
                    mSession.getVideoTrack().setVideoQuality(mQuality);
                }
                mClient.setCredentials(user, password);
                mClient.setServerAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
                mClient.setStreamPath("/"+path);
                mClient.startStream(1);

                // Init recording flag
                recording = true;

                return START_SUCCEEDED;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error starting streaiming.", e);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return START_FAILED;
            }
```

This is the error:

```
 E/CameraActivity: Error starting streaiming. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far com.mundoglass.worldglass.CameraActivity$ToggleStreamAsyncTask.doInBackground(CameraActivity.java:190)
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: E/CameraActivity: Error starting streaiming.  ----------------
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far   ---------------------
com.mundoglass.worldglass.CameraActivity$ToggleStreamAsyncTask.doInBackground(CameraActivity.java:190)

Comment: https://github.com/andermaco/GlassStream  .... this is my all code

Comment: you should edit your question to include the error.

Comment: I updated. Thx.